# st_union in R creates artifacts for global data

Tags: qgis, r, dissolve, union, antimeridian

I load this polygon data in R which global coverage.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E-atD4ZhbaQ8Zxv93sFgk9l_atLtG8eJ/view?usp=drive_link

It looks like this:

[image]

In QGIS I can run the dissolve function and get a multipolygon with only four features that looks like this:

[image]

However, when I want to do something similar in R I thought I could group by a column and summarise the data as described here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/290

However when I do the follwing:

```
 dissolved = poly %>% 
   rename(class=1) %>% 
    group_by(class) %>% 
    summarise()
```

I get this:

[image]

Any ideas on what I could do to make it achieve more the result of QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sf` has decided that bits of the earth across the -180/180 point are the same and tried to merge them, resulting in lines going across the globe. You need to tell it to stop doing that, and here's two ways.

Number one, set the crs of `poly` to NA:

```
     > poly = st_read("./poly_test.geojson")
     Reading layer `poly_test' from data source 
      `/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/SO/union/poly_test.geojson' using driver `GeoJSON'
     Simple feature collection with 4914 features and 1 field
     Geometry type: POLYGON
     Dimension:     XY
     Bounding box:  xmin: -180 ymin: -58.00664 xmax: 180 ymax: 83.52159
     Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

     > crs = st_crs(poly) # save for later
     > st_crs(poly) = NA  # set to missing

     > dissolved = poly %>% group_by(class) %>% summarise()
     > st_crs(dissolved) = crs # put it back on the output
     > plot(dissolved)
```

Producing:

[image]

The second way is to tell `sf` not to use spherical geometry:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
poly = st_read("./poly_test.geojson")
dissolved = poly %>% group_by(class) %>% summarise()
plot(dissolved)
```

which produces what looks like an identical good map without having to mess with coordinate systems, although you do get a bunch of warnings.

Another possibility, which is really fast, follows if you don't have polygons with the same category that share borders, which is to simply merge all polygons of the same category into a MULTIPOLYGON geometry, and then build a spatial data frame.

```
> mp = tapply(poly$geometry, poly$class, st_multipolygon)
> names(mp)
[1] "q1" "q2" "q3" "q4"
```

Each element of that list is a MULTIPOLYGON geometry that we can build into a 4-row spatial data frame:

```
> dissolved = st_as_sf(data.frame(
    class=names(mp), 
    geometry=do.call(st_sfc, mp)), 
   crs=st_crs(poly))
> plot(dissolved)
```